# Iterating a data table in LINQPad

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I am totally new to C# and LINQpad.

I am using the Onet22 database which contains some job related data.

```
Alternate_titles.Take(100).Select(o => o.Alternate_title).Dump("titles only");
```

This returns a table that looks like:

```
5IOrderedQueryable<String> (100 items)4 
Aeronautics Commission Director 
Agricultural Services Director 
Alcohol and Drug Abuse Assistance Program Administrator 
Arts and Humanities Council Director 
Bakery Manager 
Bank President 
Book Publisher 
Brokerage Office Manager 
Bureau Chief 
Business Development Executive 
 ...
```

and I wrote a function that takes two Strings and calculates the String similarity, but I don't get how to retrieve the String from the table.

What I need are :

1. Picking one random String from that table (`Alternate_titles`).
2. Iterating through the table and access all Strings in the table.

Comment: What do you mean you don't get how to retrieve strings? You are demonstrating that exact thing in your question. It is not really clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What do you want to do in (2) ?